# use XSLT to pare down XML output

Tags: xslt, copy

How can I using XSLT, select only some xml tags from my input xml to my output XML?
example input:

```
<Country value="USA">
    <State value="KY>
        <City value="Hebron" />
        <City value="Lexington" />
        <City value="Owensboro" />
        <City value="Jonesville" />
    </State>
    <State value="OH">
         <City value="Cincinnati" />
         <City value="Columbus" />
         <City value="Cleveland" />
         <City value="Jonesville" />
    </State>
    <State value="IN" >
         <City value="Indianapolis" />
    </State>
 </Country>
```

So, keep the Country/State tags in place and only copy Hebron and Cincinnati?

expected output:

```
<Country value="USA">
    <State value="KY>
        <City value="Hebron" />
    </State>
    <State value="OH">
         <City value="Cincinnati" />
    </State>
 </Country>
```

Comment: What defines the tags you want to keep?  First in each state?

Comment: Since you have a `<Country...>` tag it is implied that you'll have other countries, in which `<State...>` might not be appropriate (Province, Prefecture, etc).  You need to completely specify the problem.

Comment: There can be more than 1 country but for this example (not the real tags), state will suffice for other countries' provinces...

Comment: @Matt A — What should happen to `State` tags which contain no kept cities?  Should they be empty or removed?

Comment: Note the missing quote on `"KY`

Comment: State tags that don't have any Cities should be removed

Comment: @Matt A: That this is not a good question is proved by answers going for differents roads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="City[not(@value='Hebron' or @value='Cincinnati')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On this input:

```
<Country value="USA">
    <State value="KY">
        <City value="Hebron" />
        <City value="Lexington" />
        <City value="Owensboro" />
    </State>
    <State value="OH">
        <City value="Cincinnati" />
        <City value="Columbus" />
        <City value="Cleveland" />
    </State>
</Country>
```

Produces the following result:

```
<Country value="USA">
    <State value="KY">
        <City value="Hebron" />
    </State>
    <State value="OH">
        <City value="Cincinnati" />
    </State>
</Country>
```

This stylesheet uses the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy all but the undesired nodes to the output unchanged.

**Another example**

You might also want to remove any `State` element that does not have a desired city. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="City[not(@value='Hebron' or @value='Cincinnati')]"/>
    <xsl:template 
           match="State[not(City[@value='Hebron' or @value='Cincinnati'])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input:

```
<Country value="USA">
    <State value="KY">
        <City value="Hebron" />
        <City value="Lexington" />
        <City value="Owensboro" />
    </State>
    <State value="OH">
        <City value="Cincinnati" />
        <City value="Columbus" />
        <City value="Cleveland" />
    </State>
    <State value="MO">
        <City value="St. Louis" />
    </State>
</Country>
```

Produces:

```
<Country value="USA">
    <State value="KY">
        <City value="Hebron" />
    </State>
    <State value="OH">
        <City value="Cincinnati" />
    </State>
</Country>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will leave only specific cities:

```
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="City[@value != 'Hebron' and @value != 'Cincinnati']"/>
```

This will leave only first city:

```
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="City[position() &gt; 1]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my (probably inadequate) 2.0 solution. Cities are a regular expression passed as a parameter.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="Cities" select="'Cincinnati|Hebron'"/>

  <xsl:template match="State">
    <xsl:if test="exists(City[matches(@value, $Cities)])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="State/City">
    <xsl:if test="matches(@value, $Cities)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @stand: The parameter could be a sequence thus no RegExp would be needed.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yeah, I thought perhaps a regexp would provide more flexibility. So you could pick "Cities that start with C" or stuff like that. Of course then you have to be comfortable with regexes which is a whole other issue.

Comment: @stand: But more important, you must not open a window for stylesheet failure allowing a parameter that could contain a forbidden RegExp matching the empty sequence.

Comment: @Alejandro: Indeed, caveat emptor! (what's latin for caller?) If you want, s/param/variable/. I like the idea of having the city list in a single location at the top instead of repeated in multiple templates though. Am I missing any other corner cases?

Comment: @stand: The other issue with this is that your are still following XSLT 1.0 patterns restrictions (no variable/parameter references in pattern) wich do not stand in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Alejandro: Interesting! Could you demonstrate that, either by editing my answer or in a comment?

Comment: @stand: `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:param name="Cities" select="'Cincinnati','Hebron'"/>
 <xsl:template match="State[not(City/@value = $Cities)]"/>
 <xsl:template match="State/City[not(@value = $Cities)]"/>
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: I like the parameter passing idea but one further twist.  I added a city that has the same name in 2 diff states but I only want the one in KY, how would I do that?

Comment: @Alejandro- I like the parameter passing idea but one further twist. I added a city that has the same name in 2 diff states but I only want the one in KY, how would I do that? In essence, I'd like to be able to identify which attribute tags to transfer based on the state name...