# xslt variable match on XML

Tags: xml, xslt, match

I'm trying to figure out how leverage multiple templates based on attributes at lower levels of an XML doc.  Example:

```
<World>
<Country value="USA">
    <State value="KY">
        <City value="Hebron"/>
        <City value="Lexington"/>
        <City value="Owensboro"/>
        <City value="Jonesville"/>
    </State>
    <State value="OH">
        <City value="Cincinnati"/>
        <City value="Columbus"/>
        <City value="Cleveland"/>
        <City value="Jonesville"/>
    </State>
    <State value="IN">
        <City value="Indianapolis"/>
    </State>
</Country>
</World>
<World>
<Country value="Russia">
  <State value="Estonia">
        <City value="Tallinn"/>
        <City value="Dorpat"/>
        <City value="Owensboro"/>
  </State>
  <State value="Ukraine">
        <City value="Kiev"/>
        <City value="Sevastopol"/>
        <City value="Slavutych"/>
        <City value="Jonesville"/>
  </State>
</Country>
</World>
```

I'm going to receive instances of XML docs as that will either Country = USA or Russia but I won't know which.  I want to apply a single XSLT that will allow for either Country and copy different Cities as a result.

if its USA for example, the output would look like:

```
<World>
<Country value="USA">
 <State value="KY">
     <City value="Hebron" />
 </State>
 <State value="OH">
      <City value="Cincinnati" />
      <City value="Jonesville" />
 </State>
 </Country>
</World>
```

if its Russia:

```
<World>
<Country value="Russia">
 <State value="Estonia">
     <City value="Dorpat" />
     <City value="Owensboro" />
 </State>
 <State value="Ukraine">
      <City value="Keiv" />
      <City value="Sevastopol" />
      <City value="Slavutych" />
 </State>
 </Country>
</World>
```

Also note, it is possible to want a city in one state but not another state (i.e. OH vs KY, Jonesville).

I can get one country to work but I'm not grasping how to force templates to match across different attibutes.  Any ideas?

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what you're looking for, here.  What are the criteria you want to apply in choosing cities to copy to your output?

Comment: It will be defined via a set of parameters in the XSLT.  each customer might go in and change them to some other city value.

Comment: @Matt A: Complete answer depends on what data you use for this filtering. In other hand is just the same as your former [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585372/use-xslt-to-pare-down-xml-output).

Comment: OT: It's funny to see Ukraine to be the state under Russia country. Are you doing this XSLT for intelligence agency that knows about potential geopolitical changes? ;)

Comment: @Alejandro - Each user will determine his data and taylor the xslt accordingly.  So user A will pick certain combination of country/state/city and user B will pick different combinations.  I was hoping to find a pattern that would allow the user to encapsulate his choices (much like the param answer).  I'm missing something obvious I think...

Comment: @Oleg Iavorskyi - Nothing so sinister.  I tried to find another country with a country/state relationship so I didn't get comments like Canada doesn't have states.  That's what happens when you rely on wiki...

Comment: Matt, no problems, I was kidding :)

Comment: @Matt A: I should have been said that depends on used data **type**.

Comment: @Alejandro - all the data types are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet performs some basic validation/filtering:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                              xmlns:my="my">
    <my:vals>
        <v v="USA|KY|Hebron" />
        <v v="USA|OH|Cincinnati" />
        <v v="USA|OH|Jonesville" />
        <v v="Russia|Estonia|Dorpat" />
        <v v="Russia|Estonia|Owensboro" />
        <v v="Russia|Ukraine|Kiev" />
        <v v="Russia|Ukraine|Sevastopol" />
        <v v="Russia|Ukraine|Slavutych" />
    </my:vals>
    <xsl:variable name="vals" select="document('')/*/my:vals/*" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="World">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="@*|Country[State/City[
                   concat(../../@value, '|', ../@value, '|', @value)=$vals/@v]]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Country">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="@*|State[City[
                   concat(../../@value, '|', ../@value, '|', @value)=$vals/@v]]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="State">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="@*|City[
                    concat(../../@value, '|', ../@value, '|', @value)=$vals/@v]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On this input:

```
<World>
    <Country value="USA">
        <State value="KY">
            <City value="Hebron" />
            <City value="Lexington" />
            <City value="Owensboro" />
            <City value="Jonesville" />
        </State>
        <State value="OH">
            <City value="Cincinnati" />
            <City value="Columbus" />
            <City value="Cleveland" />
            <City value="Jonesville" />
        </State>
        <State value="IN">
            <City value="Indianapolis" />
        </State>
    </Country>
    <Country value="Russia">
        <State value="Estonia">
            <City value="Tallinn" />
            <City value="Dorpat" />
            <City value="Owensboro" />
        </State>
        <State value="Ukraine">
            <City value="Kiev" />
            <City value="Sevastopol" />
            <City value="Slavutych" />
            <City value="Jonesville" />
        </State>
    </Country>
</World>
```

Produces:

```
<World>
    <Country value="USA">
        <State value="KY">
            <City value="Hebron" />
        </State>
        <State value="OH">
            <City value="Cincinnati" />
            <City value="Jonesville" />
        </State>
    </Country>
    <Country value="Russia">
        <State value="Estonia">
            <City value="Dorpat" />
            <City value="Owensboro" />
        </State>
        <State value="Ukraine">
            <City value="Kiev" />
            <City value="Sevastopol" />
            <City value="Slavutych" />
        </State>
    </Country>
</World>
```

**Explanation:** We only enter `Country` elements that contain a valid `State` and `City` combination; only `State` elements that contain a valid `City`; and, then, only valid `City` elements. All invalid or empty elements are elided.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. I like fixed path, but for simplicity you could use `<xsl:template match="*"> <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::City[concat(../../@value, '|', ../@value, '|', @value) = $vals/@v]"> <xsl:call-template name="identity"/> </xsl:if> </xsl:template>`. Only copy elements having a `City` descendant matching the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that your user will specify desired cities through some kind of parametric criteria, I guess you'd do something like the following (note the "SATISFIES CRITERIA" pseudocode, since I don't know exactly what criteria a city @value needs to satisfy):

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <template match="/World">
      <copy>
         <apply-templates select="Country[ State/City[ @value SATISFIES CRITERIA ] ]" />
      </copy>
   </template>

   <template match="Country|State|@*">
      <copy>
         <apply-templates select="*|@*" />
      </copy>
   </template>

   <template match="City[ @value SATISFIES CRITERIA ]">
      <copy>
         <apply-templates select="@*" />
      </copy>
   </template>
</stylesheet>
```