# how to delete line after specific pattern and extract something

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

**UPDATE**
This is my file:

```
<department name="/fighters" id="123879" group="channel" case="none" use="no">
  <options index_name="index.html" listing="0" sum="no"  allowed="no" />
  <target prefix="ttp" suffix=".net" />
  <type="effort">
  <region="20491" readonly="fs1a" readwrite="fs1a" upload="yes" download="yes" repl="yes" hard="0" soft"0" prio="0" write="no" stage="yes" migrate="no" size="0" >
  <read="content" readwrite="content" hard="215822106624" soft="237296943104" prio="5" write="yes"  stage="yes" migrate="no" size="0" />
  <overflow name="20491-set-writable" />
</replicate>
<region="20576" readonly="fs1a" readwrite="fs1a" upload="yes" download="yes" repl="yes" hard="0" soft"0" prio="0" write="no" stage="yes" migrate="no" size="0" >
<read="content" readwrite="content" hard="215822106624" soft="237296943104" prio="5" write="yes"  stage="yes" migrate="no" size="0" />
<overflow name="20576-set-writable" />
</replicate>
</replication>
<user="T:106603" />
<user="T:123879" />
<user="test" />
<user="ele::123456" />
<user="company-temp" />
<user="companymw2" />
<user="bird" />
<user="coding11" />
<user="plazamedia" />
<allow go="123456=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />
</department>
```

I wrote a bash like:

```
awk < test.xml -Fuser= '{ print $2 }' | sed '/^$/d' |  cut -d" " -f1
```

and result is something like:

```
"T:106603"
"T:123879"
"test"
"ele::123456"
"company-temp"
"companymw2"
"bird"
"coding11"
"plazamedia"
```

But imagine the result is:

```
"T:106603" />
"T:123879" />
"test" />
"ele::123456" />
"company-temp" />
"companymw2" />
"bird" />
"coding11" />
"plazamedia" />
```

first,How can I say remove every thing after second `"`?

secondly, how can I say extract everything between `" "`?

I like doing it with `sed` or `awk`

Thank you in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to have a few full lines of output to best optimize the answer.

Comment: @ Ben Whaley I updated it

Comment: @MortezaLSC, post the sample data of `test.xml` and what is your expected output?

Comment: @sat My expected output are two: first the result in post with `cut` command(I want do it with sed and awk)///secong removing all `"` from output...or extracting everything between `" "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F'"' '/<user=/{ print $2 }' file
```

Comment: any solution with `sed`?

Comment: @MortezaLSC You can use `sed` but in this case it will be more complex with back reference and hard to understand compare to this very simple `awk`

Comment: @MortezaLSC My `sed` is a bit rusty but you can try something like `sed -n '/^\<user=/s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file`

Answer (score 1):

Try this `cut`,

```
cut -d'"' -f 2 test.xml
```

Try this `sed`,

With quotes(`"`):

```
sed 's/^.*\("[^"]\+"\).*/\1/g' test.xml
```

Without quotes(`"`):

```
sed 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/g' test.xml
```

**UPDATE:**

```
sed -e '/^<user/!{d}' -e '/^<user/s/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/' test.xml
```

Comment: I have large file..how to continue `awk < test.xml -Fuser= '{ print $2 }' | sed '/^$/d' | `?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the `sed` and `cut` in the pipeline, there are many ways to do that, depending on what the corner cases are.  The simplest to me would seem to be

```
awk -F'"' '/<user=/ { print "\"$2\"" }' test.xml
```

As usual, here's the obligatory [don't parse XML with regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) link.

Slightly interesting corner cases would be if there can be quoted double quotes in the string (but usually XML would use entities instead) or if the elements can have multiple attributes.  If there could be multiple `<user=...>` elements on a single line, this will quickly become more complex than the *proper* solution, which is to [use XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585372/use-xslt-to-pare-down-xml-output).

Answer (score 1):

Using only sed:

```
$ sed 's/^<user=\(.*"\).*/\1/' test.xml # With quotes
$ sed 's/^<user="\(.*\)".*/\1/' test.xml # Without quotes
```

Comment: should be `sed -n 's/^<user=\(.*"\).*/\1/p' test.xml`

Answer (score 1):

**Try :**

```
$ awk '/<user=/ && gsub(/<user=|\/>/,x)' file
"T:106603" 
"T:123879" 
"test" 
"ele::123456" 
"company-temp" 
"companymw2" 
"bird" 
"coding11" 
"plazamedia"
```

If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS` system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu grep

```
grep -Po 'user=\K"[^"]*"' file
```